# Using docker CMD instead of application.properties in hello world app

Tags: spring-boot, docker

In my hello world app I'm using application properties to define 'name'.
It works fine, but I want to define 'name' in docker CMD.

Service:

```
@Service
public class HelloService {

@Value("${name}")
private String name;

@GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting() {
            return "Hello, " + name;
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
name=Tommy
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I'm trying to add to Dockerfile something like this:

```
CMD ${name} Tommy
```

I run docker by:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 hello-api:1.0
```

How can i do it right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dockerfile, use ENV instead of CMD like

```
ENV NAME=Tommy
```

Then you can directly use this environment variable in your application.properties:

```
name = ${NAME}
```

The rest of your implementation would be the same.